# Shifting Byte Array

Tags: vb.net

If have an array of Bytes in visual basic:

```
Dim data() As Byte = {0, 128, 0, 4, 9, 9, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Is there a quick and easy way to insert two data values to the front of this array, and knock off the last two values?

```
Dim data() As Byte = {128, 128, 0, 128, 0, 4, 9, 9, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: Pretty pointless to use an array if you want to do this.  The proper type is a Queue(Of Byte).

Comment: @Hans, that should be an answer, not a comment.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  First you need to move all of the existing values up 2 places in your array.  Doing so will overwrite the last 2 values.  You'll then want to set the first two values of your array.

```
'Move data up 2 spots.  This needs to be done in reverse order so we don't lose any data
For i as Integer = data.Length - 1 To 2 Step -1
    data(i) = data(i - 2)
End

'Assign the new values
data(0) = 128
data(1) = 128
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the bytes into a vb.net stack with a loop then use the stack.push then rewrite the data back